# Spring boot Reactive caching

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, spring-webflux, project-reactor

In my application I am using spring webflux and I am using webclient to retrieve details from some 3rd party API. Now, I want to store the first time webClient  response in some in memory cache so that for 2nd time I can have those response directly from the cache.
I am trying to use Spring boot in memory caching mechanism and also "caffine". But none is working as expected.
**application.yml:**

```
spring:
 cache:
  cache-names: employee
 caffiene:
  spec: maximumSize=200, expireAfterAccess=5m
```

**EmployeeApplication.java:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class EmployeeApplication{
   public static void main(String[] args){
    
}
}
```

**EmployeeController.java:**
It has a rest endpoint `employee/all` which fetch all employee from the 3rd party Api.
**EmployeeService.java:**

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class EmployeeService{
  @Autowired
  private WebClient webClient;
  @Autowired
  private CacheManager cacheManager;
  @Cacheable("employee")
  public Mono<List<Employee>> getAllEmployee(){
    log.info("inside employee service {}");
    return webClient.get()
        .uri("/employees/")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Employee.class);
}
}
```

Although I have configured the cache name , 2nd time when I hit the url it is calling the service method. What cache mechanism need to be used to cache Mono response? Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several options to cache reactive publishers.

1. Use reactive `cache` API to cache `Mono` for the defined duration

```
employeeService.getAllEmployee()
    .cache(Duration.ofMinutes(60))
    .flatMap(employees -> {
        // process data
    })
```

2. Use external cache with Caffeine.

Caffeine supports async cache based on CompletableFuture that could be easily adapted to Reactive API.

```
AsyncLoadingCache<String, List<Employee>> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .buildAsync((tenant, executor) ->
            employeeService.getAllEmployee(tenant).toFuture()
    );


Mono<List<Employee>> getEmployee(String tenant) {
    return Mono.fromCompletionStage(clientCache.get(tenant));
}
```

3. Use external cache with Guava and [CacheMono](https://projectreactor.io/docs/extra/snapshot/api/reactor/cache/CacheMono.html) from `reactor-extra`. This option is more suitable if you need to cache results based on different input (e.g. multi tenant environment)

**UPDATE**: *`CacheMono` has been deprecated since reactor-extra 3.4.7. Better use #2 Use external cache with Caffeine.*

Here is an example for Guava but you could adapt it for `CacheManager`

```
Cache<String, List<Employee>> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .expireAfterWrite(cacheTtl)
        .build();


Mono<List<Employee>> getEmployee(String tenant) {
    return CacheMono.lookup(key -> Mono.justOrEmpty(cache.getIfPresent(key)).map(Signal::next), tenant)
            .onCacheMissResume(() -> employeeService.getAllEmployee(tenant))
            .andWriteWith((key, signal) -> Mono.fromRunnable(() ->
                            Optional.ofNullable(signal.get())
                                    .ifPresent(value -> cache.put(key, value))
                    )
            );
}
```

Comment: Hi @Alex thanks for the answer.For the 1st options r u referring the inbuild spring boot cache mechanism. I have tried that but not getting result from cache. For the 2nd one can you please share some reference.

Comment: The first example has no relation to spring boot cache mechanism. this is pure reactive API. The key here is to reuse cached `Mono`.  for example, you could store it in some class field  `Mono<...> cachedList = employeeService.getAllEmployee().cache(Duration.ofMinutes(60));` and then use it in your flow. Otherwise new publisher will be created and returned from the method.

Comment: in my case I need to pass my organization Id at run time and the value is coming from controller. That's means should I use that cache variable in my controller class.

Comment: For 2nd options , as I need to return a Mono list of objects it says that bad return type in lambda expression. Mono<List<Employee>> can't be converted to Mono<String>.

Comment: Updated the example. You need to define you guava cache as `Cache<String, List<Employee>> cache` but the it will be resolved async as `Mono<List<Employee>>`

Comment: Thanks @Alex it is working now.I have taken your 2nd options.

Comment: `CacheMono` has been deprecated since `reactor-extra` 3.4.7 (released March 15, 2022), and is slated for removal in 3.6.0: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons/issues/237

Answer (score 3):

We can use Mono.cache() and still avoid caching exceptions/errors and thus avoiding memory leaks. I found the below article that shows how to do it.

https://nickolasfisher.com/blog/InMemory-Caching-in-Sprint-Boot-WebfluxProject-Reactor

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34483937)

Answer (score 1):

A warning when using Mono.cache(): It caches Exceptions as well.

We just produced a very effective leak by combining Mono.cache() with Springs @Cachable and Coffein and one more library that added a suppressed exception to the thrown exception. Since it was always the identical exception thrown from cache, suppressed exceptions where accumulating on this exception. All that resulted in a runaway situation as soon as the cached exeption was logged. Up to 3 cores used explicitly for logging since the exception messages got so long with all the supressed exceptions.
And the initial exception was a timeout.