# How to combine Flux from multiple publishers and process all of them

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have the following reactive chain defined:

```
Flux<Tuple3<A, B, C>> enrich(List<String> idList) {
    return aEnricher.getAById(idList)
        .zipWith(bEnricher.getBByLookupId(lookupIds))
        .zipWith(cEnricher.getCByLookupId(lookupIds))
        .map(tuple -> Tuples.of(tuple.getT1().getT1(), tuple.getT1().getT2(), tuple.getT2()));
}
```

Function Signatures:

```
Flux<A> getAById(List<String> idList)
Flux<B> getBByLookupId(List<String> lookupIds)
Flux<C> getCByLookupId(List<String> lookupIds)
```

`lookupId` is received as part of object `A` from the first api call.

This is called here:

```
combinedEnricher.enrich(events).subscribe(this::processTuple);
```

My question is this. I have multiple different enrichers to be added to `zipWith`. As per documentation, `zipWith` will complete when one of the publisher completes. But in my case, different enrichers will emit different number of Flux and I need to process all of them.

How can I achieve this? Since the Flux types are different, I cannot use merge here

**EDIT**

Option A

```
aEnricher.getAById(idList).buffer(10).subscribe( lookupIds -> {
    bEnricher.getBByLookupId(lookupIds).subscribe();
    cEnricher.getCByLookupId(lookupIds).subscribe();
}

Mono<Void> getBByLookupId(List<String> lookupIds) {
    Flux.just(lookupIds)
    .flatMap(lookupId -> serviceB.callApi(lookupId))
    .map(this::convertToAnotherObject)
    .doOnNext(this::sendToKafka)
    .then();
}

Mono<Void> getCByLookupId(List<String> lookupIds) {
    Flux.just(lookupIds)
    .flatMap(lookupId -> serviceC.callApi(lookupId))
    .map(this::convertToAnotherObject)
    .doOnNext(this::sendToKafka)
    .then();
}
```

Option B

```
aEnricher.getAById(idList)
            .buffer(10)
            .flatMap(lookupIds -> 
                    Mono.zip(
                            Mono.just(lookupIds),
                            aEnricher.getBByLookupId(lookupIds).collectList(), 
                            aEnricher.getCByLookupId(lookupIds).collectList()
                    )
            )
            .map(convertToTuple3)
            .map(this::sendToKafka)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot Reactive caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71532361/spring-boot-reactive-caching)

Comment: I don't think so. How do I pass a Mono as argument to the methods when they are expecting a list?

Comment: Could you add signatures of ‘getAById’ and ‘getBByLookupId’ to better understand the problem

Comment: Should be idList present as an argument of method enrich() ?

Comment: Added function signatures

Comment: @Alex Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: getAById and getXByLookupId returns multiple elements? How do you want to combine them in the result Flux? Do they always return the same number of elements?

Comment: It could be different number of elements. Hence I cannot use zip

Answer (score 1):

Based on the update question I would propose the following

```
Flux<Void> enrich(List<String> idList) {
    return enricher.getAById(idList)
            .buffer(10)
            .flatMap(lookupIds ->
                    Mono.zip(
                            sendToKafka(Flux.fromIterable(lookupIds)),
                            sendToKafka(enricher.getBByLookupId(lookupIds)),
                            sendToKafka(enricher.getCByLookupId(lookupIds))
                    ).then()
            );
}
```

This logic assumes that `getXByLookupId` returns `Flux<T>`.

Having in mind you are using Reactor Kafka, `sendToKafka` could look like. Probably you would need to have `sendToKafka` for every specific type.

```
private <T> Mono<Void> sendToKafka(Flux<T> data) {
        return kafkaSender.createOutbound()
                .send(data)
                .then();
    }
```

Comment: I have updated my question with 2 options. I wanted to understand the difference between option A and B. Is zip the only option to run apis parallel? What about calling subscribe on individual chains and let each chain perform all actions needed on its result and return a `Mono<Void>`? In case of zip, I need to process all items in tuple and perform actions on all of them.

Comment: Also, Mono<List> will limit the parallelism within the list

Comment: I don’t see any limitation in your case. In any case it would be useful if you provide example output for every case and describe logic in pseudo code. It’s still not clear what is the result data structure

Comment: What data do you want to send to Kafka as a result of this flow?

Comment: As for your options - definitely not "Option A" but still not really clear what is `AnotherObject` you are sending to Kafka. Try to describe this data structure without reactive.

Comment: This is the use-case. Input is list of ids. First call enricherA obtain A as result. Take `lookupId` field from A and pass it to enricherB , enricherC etc. They will return B and C respectively. Now I need to send A, B, C to Kafka. We need to pass list of lookUpId to enricherB and enricherC to enable batching. Sending to kafka can be done at any time, either as soon as result is ready or at the end after waiting for A,B,C

Comment: updated the answer based on the above description

Comment: I tried this approach. Looks like the `zip` is getting completed fast. It does not wait for all of them to complete.

Comment: ’zip’ returns Tuple with result of all publishers. You can add ‘.doOnNext’ and log results or add ‘.log’ operator to see result signal

Comment: Since `sendToKafka` returns `Mono<Void>` I used `Flux.merge` instead of `zip` which seems to be working