# How to invoke multiple api calls with same arguments using flatMap

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, flatmap

```
Mono<Void> enrich(List<String> idList) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(idList)
         .flatMap(idList -> aEnricher.getAById(idList))
         .map(aEnrichResponse -> aEnrichResponse.getLookupId())
         .buffer(10)
        .flatMap(lookupIdList -> bEnricher.getBByLookupId(lookupIdList))  //WRONG: idList is not available, but response of previous call is available
        .map(bResponse -> save(bResponse))
        .flatMap(lookupIdList-> cEnricher.getCByLookupId(lookupIdList)); //WRONG: same as above
        .map(cResponse -> save(cResponse))
```

}

How can I call multiple calls (bEnricher and cEnricher) simultaneously with same arguments. I cannot use `merge` or `zip` since return types and return size are different

Comment: What is the expected result of the above flow? It looks like `.getBByLookupId` & `getCByLookupId` returns `Flux` but results are ignored. In this case you could convert `Flux` to `Mono<List>` using `collectList` and then use `.merge` to resolve them in parallel.

Comment: The need is to call aEnricher and then pass the lookUpIds to multiple enricher calls. Each enricher call gives different type of response and different number of results. Need to perform action on each result. Can you please provide a snippet to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine Flux from multiple publishers and process all of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75048912/how-to-combine-flux-from-multiple-publishers-and-process-all-of-them)