# Cache method results in WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I would like to cache results for  a method like the following using WebFlux (Project Reactor)

```
Flux<Customer> customers = customerService.getCustomersByCityAndAge("NY", "25")
```

(I often see unrealistic examples caching method without parameters etc... but generally this is not the case)

1. Cache results with a TTL
2. Cache results when a certain external condition verifies (for ex. a message on a queue is received)

thank you for your help

Comment: That is what Spring Cache already does (at least 1). Not sure what you mean with 2?

Comment: i think you just simply add @Cacheable("customer") on ur method

Comment: No : @Cacheable annotation does not work with reactive (Flux/Mono)...I tried it in Project Reactor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot Reactive caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71532361/spring-boot-reactive-caching)

Comment: Sorry for the delay @Alex, that answer my question partially, because getAll Employe() ha no parameters.

Comment: there is no difference with parameters. You can still use both approaches

Comment: if I do Mono<Customer> customers = getCustomers("one").cache(10s) and then I subscribe to customers I will never obtain results from  getCustomers("two").cache() so it seems to me that I cannot use the "same" approach, maybe I'm missing something ?