# Is there a way to cache responses using Mono from a WebClient call?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient, publisher

Is there a way to cache the response from a call if the inputs are the same?  For example, if the fileName is the same, I don't want to make the request out with my webClient again since it takes a while for the response.

```
Flux.fromIterable(files).flatMap(
  file -> {
     Mono<String> extension = getExtension(file.getName());
   });

public Mono<String> getExtension(String fileName) {
  return webClient.get().uri(extensionUrl + "?file=" + fileName).retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(String[].class)
    .map(
      extensions -> {
        System.out.println("finished retrieving");
        return extensions[0];
      });
}
```

Comment: Reactor doesn't provide any caching layer, but you can use any existing library or a plain `Map` for caching, then check for an existing value before making the call. And put one on `doOnNext`.

Comment: Thanks @IgorArtamonov! Yes my original plan was to use a hashmap... something like: `HashMap<String, Mono<String>> cache = new HashMap<String, Mono<String>>();` where the key would be the fileName and then the value would be the Mono<String> but i'm having problems figuring out how to get the response from the webClient call... it seems like it just keeps making the requests to the extensionUrl until all files are iterated... then they all return "finished retrieving" back to back to back.  That defeats the purpose of my cache

Comment: I think this article answers your question: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-cacheable

Comment: here are some hints https://stackoverflow.com/a/71533892/9068895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactor doesn't provide any caching layer, but you can use any existing library or a plain `Map` for caching, then check for an existing value before making the call. And put one on `doOnNext`.

Caching an original `Mono` itself may not work because it depends on actual implementation and in many cases a new subscription to it will cause a new request (but see below).

So the simplest implementation would be:

```
private Map<String, String> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap();

public Mono<String> getExtension(String fileName) {
   String existing = cache.get(fileName);
   if (existing != null) {
       return Mono.just(existing);
   }

   return webClient.get().uri(extensionUrl + "?file=" + fileName).retrieve()
       .bodyToMono(String[].class)
       .map(....)
       .doOnNext(value -> cache.put(fileName, value));
}
```

If you want to avoid duplicate in-flight requests as well, then it makes sense to cache the `Mono`. But in this case I would suggest to ether use it with `.cache()`, or even use a `Sinks.One` as an intermediary.

The simplified code would look like:

```
private Map<String, Mono<String>> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap();

public Mono<String> getExtension(String fileName) {
   Mono<String> existing = cache.get(fileName);
   if (existing != null) {
       return existing;
   }

   Mono<String> requested = webClient.get().uri(extensionUrl + "?file=" + fileName).retrieve()
       .bodyToMono(String[].class)
       .map(....)
       // you probably don't want to keep failed requests in cache
       .doOnError(t -> cache.remove(fileName))
       .cache();
   cache.put(fileName, requested);

   return requested;
}
```